# How can i shorten his code? (Multiple File paths)

Tags: python

I made a file sorter program that puts files in my downloads to their correct folder. This block looks ugly though

```
wordpath = path + "Word"
musicpath = path + "Music"
imagepath = path + "Images"
zippath = path + "Zips"
exepath = path + "Programs"
otherpath = path + "Other"
```

I thought of putting the words in a list but idk how to set the correct variable names in a for loop. 
Thanks.

Comment: If you don't need individual variables in the end, you could stick all suffix strings in a list, then do `[path + suff for suff in suffixes]`. That'll give you a list. You could also use a dictionary comprehension. What do you want to end up with?

Comment: There is no way to shorten this without changing what it does. You should give more context and you should say why you want to shorten it.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a dictionary to dynamically build up a list of values:

```py
names = ['Word', 'Music', 'Images', 'Zips', 'Programs', 'Other']
namedPaths = dict([(name, path + name) for name in names])

print(namedPaths.get('Word'))
```

Or, as suggested by [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) you could further shorten this by using a dictionary comprehension:

```py
names = ['Word', 'Music', 'Images', 'Zips', 'Programs', 'Other']
namedPaths = {name: path + name for name in names}

print(namedPaths.get('Word'))
```

Comment: You can use a dictionary comprehension rather than calling `dict()` on a list comprehension.

Comment: `{name: path+name for name in names}`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it totally slipped my mind. I have edited the answer with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You could save it in lists or dicts. Another point would be you should use `os.path.join()` to concatenate paths.

```
import os

path = "somepath"

[os.path.join(path, dir) for dir in ["Word", "Music", "Images"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

My first question is going to be: "Do you really need all those variables?"

In other words, would it be more efficient to treat the destination as "data" instead of "code" and use a `dict` or `list` to store the results.

I suspect your code might look like this:

if ... something something 'mp3':
       move_file_to(musicpath)
   elif ... something something 'exe':
       move_file_to(exepath)

And I'm wondering if a better result might not look like:

```
extension_to_path = { 'exe' : path + 'Programs',
    'mp3' : path + 'Music',
    ... etc ...
}

# ...
for file in files:
    ext = get_extension(file)
    if ext not in extension_to_path:
        print("File type not recognized:", file)
    else:
        move_file_to(extension_to_path(file))
```

I suggest you consider posting all of your code on the [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) site for a whole-program review.

With that out of the way, a specific answer to your specific question might look like this:

```
path = '/path/to/'   # NOTE trailing slash
a,b,c,d = (path + word for word in "A B C D".split())
print(a,b,c,d)

/path/to/A /path/to/B /path/to/C /path/to/D
```

So you could assign:

```
wordpath, musicpath, imagepath, zippath, exepath, otherpath = (path + w for w in "Word Music Images Zips Programs Other".split())
```

But please note: this "shortens" the code to a single line, but it makes it harder to understand because the line-wise association of `wordpath` with `Word` is gone. Now you have to count spaces and suchlike, and it doesn't support spaces in directory names. I'd recommend keeping your existing structure, except for my comments above about using data instead of code.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want them as separate variables and not stored in `dict` (such as Steve's answer suggests) you can use `exec()`. Now I wouldn't do it the following way but if it is what you want:

```
path = "/my/path/"
categories = ['Word', 'Music', 'Images', 'Zips', 'Programs', 'Other']
for category in categories:
    exec(category.lower() + 'path = ' + '"' + path + category + '"')

print(wordpath) # -> "/my/path/Word"
print(imagespath) # -> "/my/path/Images"
```